# Function call problem if protocol is passed to argument

Tags: swift

I made a simple sample code using protocol and generic.
I want to call doSomething() inside the foo() function.
The following calls work well, and the logs are printed as I expected.
`simpleA.doSomething(item: 300) // print -> [SimpleA] value property: 100, item argument: 300`
`simpleB.doSomething(item: 400) // print -> [SimpleB] value property: 200.0, item argument: 400.0`

The following syntax inside the foo() function results in a compilation error.
`simple.doSomething(item: 500)`
`simple.doSomething(item: 600)`

Can't I pass the Int or Double value as a parameter inside doSomething?

```swift
protocol SimpleProtocol {
    associatedtype MyType
    func doSomething(item: MyType)
}

struct SimpleA<T>: SimpleProtocol {
    typealias MyType = T
    
    private let value: T
    
    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func doSomething(item: T) {
        print("[SimpleA] value property: \(value), item argument: \(item)")
    }
}

struct SimpleB<T>: SimpleProtocol {
    typealias MyType = T
    
    private let value: T
    
    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func doSomething(item: T) {
        print("[SimpleB] value property: \(value), item argument: \(item)")
    }
}

class Sample {
    func debugMethod() {
        let simpleA = SimpleA<Int>(value: 100)
        let simpleB = SimpleB<Double>(value: 200)
        
        // It works well
        simpleA.doSomething(item: 300) // print -> [SimpleA] value property: 100, item argument: 300
        simpleB.doSomething(item: 400) // print -> [SimpleB] value property: 200.0, item argument: 400.0

        // It doesn't work well.
        foo(simpleA)
        foo(simpleB)
    }
    
    func foo<P: SimpleProtocol>(_ simple: P) {
        // Compile Error
        // error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'P.MyType'
        simple.doSomething(item: 500)
        simple.doSomething(item: 600)
        simple.doSomething(item: 700)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Forget about all your other code, and concentrate just on the protocol and on the function `foo`. Pretend this is all you've got:

```
protocol SimpleProtocol {
    associatedtype MyType
    func doSomething(item: MyType)
}
func foo<P: SimpleProtocol>(_ simple: P) { 
    simple.doSomething(item: 500)
}
```

That won't compile. SimpleProtocol is a generic on the placeholder type MyType. You have to resolve that placeholder type. For example:

```
func foo<P: SimpleProtocol>(_ simple: P) where P.MyType == Int {
    simple.doSomething(item: 500)
}
```

Otherwise, there is no reason for the compiler to believe that `500` can go where a MyType is expected.

---

That, after all, is what you are doing when you declare `simpleA` as a  `SimpleA<Int>`. You are *resolving* SimpleA's placeholder type T as Int. And you have also said, in SimpleA, that it resolves SimpleProtocol's MyType to its own T:

```
typealias MyType = T
```

So for SimpleA, SimpleProtocol's MyType is explicitly resolved to Int. And in the same way, for SimpleB, SimpleProtocol's MyType is explicitly resolved to Double. But you are not doing anything like that for `foo`.

---

So if you want to be able to call `foo` with both `simpleA` and `simpleB`, you could have *two* versions of `foo`:

```
func foo<P: SimpleProtocol>(_ simple: P) where P.MyType == Int {
}
func foo<P: SimpleProtocol>(_ simple: P) where P.MyType == Double {
}
```

Now all the rest of your code compiles. This multiplicity of `foo` versions may seem like a pain, and indeed it is, but that is exactly what Swift itself must do; look at how many versions of `+` it contains!

---

To embrace *both* Int *and* Double in `foo`, use Numeric. You would use it like this:

```
func foo<P: SimpleProtocol>(_ simple: P) where P.MyType : Numeric {
```

Now you can get by with just one version of `foo` once again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The following error is now occurring.
```foo(simpleB)```
```error: instance method 'foo' requires the types 'SimpleB<Double>.MyType' (aka 'Double') and 'Int' be equivalent```
Is there any way to determine the type of Generic within DoSomething()?

Comment: You cannot resolve the same placeholder two different ways at once! You would need one foo for Int and another foo for Double.

Comment: @user3569109 maybe you can do `func foo<P: SimpleProtocol>(_ simple: P) where P.MyType == Numeric {` both [`Int`](https://swiftdoc.org/v4.2/type/int/) and [`Double`](https://swiftdoc.org/v4.2/type/double/) inherit the `Numeric` protocol

Comment: @Honey very good, except you have to use colon rather than equal sign.